# removing partial shapes/objects

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, mask

I have a template on the artboard and I am using basic shapes to fill the template with designs. Some shapes overlap the template. I want to remove the parts that go outside the template box. I have tried using pathfinders and then scissors. With scissors it deletes the edge of the box too and leaves an outline. With pathfinder it deletes everything except the part I don't want.

Any simple ideas of how to do this

Comment: I'm getting the impression that [this](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28128/in-pathfinder-window-what-is-the-difference-between-a-shape-mode-and-a-pathfind) could help you, sounds like some trouble with the pathfinder tool

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you are looking for is a `Clipping Mask`.

Example artwork:
[image: 1]

Place a rectangle the same size as your artboard above everything you wish to crop:
[image: 2]

Making sure the rectangle is on top, select all artwork that you wish to have clipped:
[image: 3]

Create a clipping mask:
[image: 4]

Final result:
[image: 5]

I hope that is what you were looking for?