# How can I join a path to a compound shape in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder

I'm struggling to join the compound shape and path I have created in Illustrator. My usual click and hope in the pathfinder dialog is not working. See attached screenshots.[image]

The selected path is blue, the shape is green.

Comment: You can not. First you have to convert your stroke to outline path by select objects > path > outline stroke and then unite it.

Comment: Rather than the 'click and hope' approach, Scott has answered a question [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28128/in-pathfinder-window-what-is-the-difference-between-a-shape-mode-and-a-pathfind) that basically explains everything in the pathfinder window :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) expand the stroke appearance of the wire (with the stroke selected Go to Object>Expand>check fill and Stroke>OK)
2) merge/add to the path socket or Select them all then Use Shape Builder Tool and clean residual paths.
3) clean/adjust the connection between them (remove some points)