# Illustrator's Unite Mode Fills In Whole Layer

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am trying to recreate [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-gXH5G2vD-k&index=17&list=PLYfCBK8IplO4X-jM1Rp43wAIdpP2XNGwP) section in a tutorial I completed earlier this week. I start off with a trace I made that is comprised of paths and paths with custom width profiles and strokes applied. The whole drawing has been grouped.
[image: original grouped trace]

Now, following the tutorial (reference starts at 3:58), I expand appearance to convert the strokes into shapes, and expand the entire composition to convert the paths into shapes giving me individual shapes that are overlapping each other.
[image: expanded drawing]

It is my understanding that now I click unite to attach all shapes involved into one single vector composition. But, when I click unite, it turns into a black square.
[image: black square after pressing unite]

I have tried rereading about the unite function, and I have checked for masks, because I had one on earlier (which I released), but I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: ermm.. I don't understand, the "Unite" button *unites* all objects, if that's *not* what you want, don't use the Unite button.

Comment: Sorry, I see how that could be confusing. I am trying to unite all the shapes, but instead of connecting everything, the entire artboard turns black and I wind up with a united black square.

Comment: @user2168046 - were the shapes in a clipping mask?

Comment: I double checked. There aren't any masks.

Comment: Mind posting a picture example?

Comment: Sure, I'll get one up shortly.

Comment: Do all those shapes have fills?

Comment: All of them except for the lines on the shirt that radiate around the neck. When clicking on one it shows transparent stroke and a question mark for fill. Ungrouping puts the fill back to black.

Comment: I can't answer while this is question is on hold, but what you want is Pathfinder > Merge and *not* Pathfinder > Unite.

Comment: Yep, that did it. Now I'm wondering what made the difference between this situation and the example in the tutorial which used unite. Thanks. I'll be waiting for the official answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to understand what `Pathfinder > Unite` does.

**Unite** is intended to *combine* all fills and strokes into *one object* with the same fill/stroke as the top object in the stack.

So, in your example, if those white areas are white *fills* the result is a single shape using whatever the top object's fill color is. In this case it would appear the top object has a black fill. So everything is "united" and a black fill is used.

If you want the art to be combined, but only combined where fills are the same, you'll want to use `Pathfinder > Merge`. **Merge** only "unites" areas of *identical* fills/strokes. Merge does *not* combine areas of different colors.

You may find [**THIS QUESTION**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28128/in-pathfinder-window-what-is-the-difference-between-a-shape-mode-and-a-pathfind) of use. It explains the various Pathfinder operations.

In the tutorial you were viewing/reading it is possible that artist did *not* use white fills. If the art was *only* comprised of the black areas, Unite would work fine. It's the varying fill colors which change the results of the Unite command.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is stumbling across this post 3 years later - I had something similar happen to me today and after running a few searches for "white fills" or similar, I forgot to check for items with "no fill & no stroke"

Once I did that (and then deleted those shapes from my artboard) and tried to unite my shapes again, I got the desired result!

Hope this helps anyone else who might see it!