# Adobe Illustrator - Merging Objects and Deleting the Area Inbetween

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, smartobject

I have made a dart board on AI using elipse tool with 5 layers. Now I would like to clean the white areas to make white areas transparent but if I remove them the circular shape compeletely removes. how can i achieve it?[image]

As you can see below the white elipse shape compeletely gone

[image]

Comment: `Pathfinder > Merge` then select the white, hit delete.

Comment: I would say delete the white from the black using Pathfinder>Shape Modes>Minus Front. That will give him the transparency he's looking for.

Comment: `Merge` often works better due to it's removal of underlying objects: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28128/in-pathfinder-window-what-is-the-difference-between-a-shape-mode-and-a-pathfind/28129#28129

Comment: @Scott `Merge` does work similarly to `Divide`, but you  missed a step to `Ungroup` the merged shape before the "select the white, hit delete" step. Make sure to edit and add to your comment for future reference. Thanks!

Comment: @ErickP `Minus Front` wouldn't work in this case without extra steps. When selecting a stack of shapes, `Minus Front` will remove all of the shapes above the one at the very back. All of the inner circles would be removed using `Minus Front`, leaving only a single outer ring.

Comment: meh.. using the Direct Select Tool you don't need to ungroup. :)

Comment: @paulmz Same amount of steps using either "divide" or "minus front". In this particular case it's a total of 3 steps. So you can  use either method.    See video example:  https://youtu.be/XPWiQf8pcco

Comment: @ErickP The amount of steps are irrelevant. Minus front does not work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the Pathfinder:

1. Select all of the shapes (white and black).
2. In the Pathfinder palette, press `Divide`.
3. Select the circle and `Ungroup`.
4. Select the white circles and press `Delete`.

[image]

[image]

NOTE: Always do something like this on a copy of the original version... in case you make a mistake.

Comment: @Brock - You're welcome! Don't forget to mark the correct answer with a green check mark. Thanks!

Comment: Again, same amount of steps as "Minus Front".

Comment: Again- @ErickP The amount of steps are irrelevant. Minus front does not work in this case.

Comment: Your wrong, it does, hence my example. The steps were one of your original reasons for not using minus front but it does indeed work in this case and equally as well as using divide.

Comment: @ErickP - Prove it. And provide specific steps to your process.

Comment: i posted a video. Did you actually see it? Link in previous reply.

Comment: @ErickP - How did you draw your circles? You should show how you set the circles since Minus Front would require them to be a certain way to work effectively. Your video method does show some of the extra steps I was referring to. It's not that Minus Front is the wrong way, it just isn't the easiest since it requires more foresight than an amatuer would anticipate. And please post a thorough answer next time instead of just a vague comment. Thanks!

Comment: @paulmz:  Unfortunately I can't always post as detailed an answer as I'd like due to the fact that I have work/projects that take priority. We all try to help in our spare time as best as we can. But to briefly answer the question, the "circles" were drawn with the shape tool in the different sizes and then centered horizontally and vertically. "Brock" must have gone another route because his circles have way too many points but guessing its the same general idea. Solid circles layered on top of each other. Again, just for a visual example, I will try to redo the example video and add a link.