# Illustrator - "Please Select Two Overlapping Paths"

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder

I have two objects, a rectangle and a flower pattern.  They are overlapping.  One is a group, the other is a rectangle.  I would like to crop the flower pattern using the overlap of the two.

I'm getting the error: "The filter produced no results.  Please select two overlapping paths"

They are clearly overlapped, so perhaps one of them doesn't count as a path.  What does this error mean?

[image]

I have tried searching this issue and found multiple things that weren't helpful.  I'm trying to follow these instructions: [Illustrator: how to intersect shapes properly](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/86647/illustrator-how-to-intersect-shapes-properly)

Comment: Minus front does work, so it clearly knows how to intersect the two objects.  It just doesn't like the intersect command for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than creating a *group* for the flower pattern. Select it all and create a **Compound Path** (`Object > Compound path > Make`). And *then* try the Pathfinder command.

---

I'm *not* 100% certain this solves your issue, but it would be my first step.

`Intersect` expects to see 2 **paths**, not a path and a group. By creating a compound *path*, there will be 2 *paths*.

Comment: That makes sense.  Is there a reason that the error message wasn't something more along the lines of "one of the selected objects is not a path" or "only one path found"?  I'm thinking of putting in a feature request for a clearer error message.

Comment: The message is just universal standard when 2 paths aren't selected. Forgive me, but your suggestions essentially state the *exact same thing* just in a different way.  It seems fairly clear to me.. the selection does not contain 2 paths. If you select 1 path and hit intersect, you get the same message. More detailed messages *may* be nice, but I don't think the app really needs the overhead of detecting what is actually selected. Once a user understands the operation/message they never really need to know the "why" again.

Comment: I should note I've been a programmer for 20 years.  It's a purely philosophical perspective, but I believe having to put an error message into a search engine in order to understand it is poor design.  As for overhead, it could be a half hour of developer time and a nanosecond of processing, or it could be an hour of client time and this entire discussion.  It doesn't go away by them doing nothing, it just get moved to client side.

Comment: I don't really disagree. I'm merely aware that *engineers* don't determine what happens with Adobe products... the accounting and marketing departments determine areas of focus. Better defined messages don't garner new subscriptions. The message has been *exactly* the same since Pathfinder was introduced in version 7.0, decades ago.