# Stray empty paths within a larger path

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a path created via merging a lot of smaller paths and for whatever reason this time around, it's absolutely filled with stray points and lines. I've run path > clean up and received the "no clean up necessary" message, and select > stray points doesn't select anything.
Here's what I'm dealing with:
[image: thousands of selected lines inside of a shape]
Any way I can get rid of these without individually selecting them all? They seem to be permanently attached to my path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the art and try hitting the **Unite** button on the **Pathfinder Panel**. (`Window > Pathfinder`)

Pathfinder operations: 
 [In Pathfinder window, what is the difference between a shape mode and a pathfinder?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28128/in-pathfinder-window-what-is-the-difference-between-a-shape-mode-and-a-pathfind)

You may also be able to select just the outer path via the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow) and **lock it** (`Object > Lock`). Then you can **click-drag** with the Direct selection Tool to select the inner paths and hit Delete without mistakenly removing the large outer path. Then unlock the outer path (`Object > Unlock All`).

In addition, if they are *truly empty paths*, as in no fill no stroke, you may be able to select one... then choose `Select > Same > Fill & Stroke` to select them all, then just hit the Delete key.

You could use the **Layers Panel** to target the entire layer (or group), if appropriate, then shift-click the outer path in the Panel to deselect *that* and then hit Delete to remove the inner paths.

Comment: Unite hasn't been affecting it, but locking the outline worked great, thanks so much!