# Merge Illustrator objects into one object not group?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How do I merge several objects into a single object? I have many sloppy looking objects that when combined they create the one final object that looks great. If I could print out the vector but then keep it vectored that is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You might try selecting everything, then clicking the **Unite** button on the **Pathfinder Panel**.

More info on the Pathfinder commands ----- > *[**HERE**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/28129/3270)*