# unite illustrator << need to get way i dont want lose colors

Tags: adobe-illustrator

i need help i want to get way to do unite and compound path without losing colors becoz i want uploaded into Circut design SVG FILE . i want to get the logo same as shown in first pic with unite and compound path

[image: this before unite]

[image: this second pic after unite]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Uniting all these elements will result in one solid circle. I'm not sure what you are expecting to happen, but that is what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 4):

You do **not** want to use Unite. Unite means "make everything one object of the same color".

Try using **Merge** on the Pathfinder Panel. This will combine areas of *similar* color but not those of different colors.

Possibly helpful: [In Pathfinder window, what is the difference between a shape mode and a pathfinder?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28128/in-pathfinder-window-what-is-the-difference-between-a-shape-mode-and-a-pathfind)