# Remove hidden parts of strokes in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, stroke, pathfinder

I am trying to optimize a file to draw it with a plotter.

If I use the file "as-is" a lot of strokes will be drawn by the plotter that are actually not visible parts of the drawing.

So I would like to remove all the parts of strokes that are not visible.
In this screenshot, I highlighted the kind of strokes I want to remove on the jogger woman, while I already removed all the invisible strokes for the man (a long process!).

[image]

The only way I can think of right now would be to rasterize the image and then image trace it, but ideally there would be a less destructive way of doing that?

Comment: There is a non-destructive way of merging shapes in Illustrator. Look up the Shaper Tool, and Shaper Goups, however in this instance I don't think it will work for you.  The problem is that it's non-destructive and so the underlying paths will still be there in reality. A more practical possibility is to use the Shape Builder tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **Pathfinder: Trim** Option:

[image: Pathfinder Trim]

Comment: Amazing! Thanks! This should be super useful for people using Illustrator to prepare files for pen plotters!

Comment: @MicroMachine **Merge** is *very often* better than Trim. Both are *very similar* but there is a slight difference. **[See here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28128/in-pathfinder-window-what-is-the-difference-between-a-shape-mode-and-a-pathfind/28129#28129)**

Answer (score 0):

Use (shape builder tool)........
[image: shape builder tool]

Comment: I don't know why this was down voted. It's correct. It may not be the fastest, easiest, method. It is is a method which will work. Hopefully my +1 takes away some of the sting regarding the down votes. Welcome!

Comment: I had flagged this as spam because it basically duplicated the existing answer and came with an unsolicited link from a 1-rep user. Now that the link is gone I will retract my spam flag.

Comment: With that link.. yeah.. I could see that -- which is why I removed the link.