# Simplifying vector graphic output of finite element method result

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have quite a huge output file from a finite element method calculation (15MB). Each triangle, which represents the finite elements, is it's own object even though big areas (especially the surrounding) has the same value, hence, the same color. Is there any way to simplify such an file automatically? E.g. with Illustrator?

Edit: Here is an example picture of such a finite element method output.
[image]

This picture shows the underlaying mesh. Each trinagle is filled with a color which leads to the output above. Edit2: I changed this picture to the actual outline displayed in Illustrator (ctrl+y)
[image]

I hope it is more clear now, why there are so many paths and why there is so much data in the output picture.

Comment: Probably.. kind of need some visual reference though.

Comment: Sound like pathfinder could do this hard to say.

Comment: @Scott I thought so but sadly I can't show a picture because of confidentiality. I'll try to find one on the internet where i can explain it better.

Comment: @joojaa If you could give me another hint how to execute your idea, I could tell if it helps :)

Comment: [This](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28128/in-pathfinder-window-what-is-the-difference-between-a-shape-mode-and-a-pathfind) may help. Offhand, I'd say object > expand, then Pathfinder > Merge -- but.. if you've got gradients as in the top image, that's not going to work.

Comment: @Scott I'll try it but yes, the upper picture with the gradients (the colorful one) is the actual output I want to process. The lower one is just for explanation, why there is so many data.

Comment: You can't really simplify multiple shapes with various gradient fills.

Comment: I see that, but would it be possible to join all triangles with the same color to one big object (e.g. the big cyan area in the upper picture)? I guess that this would reduce the size already.

Comment: Thats what merge does.

Comment: Merge will combine objects that touch and have the same fill. Honestly, I think it would take direct file examination to even know if Merge will work or if there's another method. If all those outer paths in the second image are just paths with no discernible visual correlation, it may be easier to just delete them and add a color filled rectangle behind the focus area - again, not sure without file examination.

Comment: Merge worked partly. It merged the areas with the same color but it also deleted the black lines and the blue lines (with the small rectangle in each corner) completely. These lines are of vital importance! @Scott I can provide the vector graphic file from the picture shown above. Which document format would you prefer?

Comment: Eeek.. yeah thing is direct file assistance is somewhat off topic - needs to be beneficial for all users, not merely one user and all that. It also opens the floodgates for endless file troubleshooting which is not the point of this stack. But.. step back... select 1 black line, choose `Select > Same > Fill & Stroke`, then choose `Object > Lock` -- do the same for the blue lines... then do the Merge (this should leave the black/blue lines untouched). Then, `Object > Unlock All` to free up the black/blue lines again.

Comment: I was able to preserve the lines with executing an `Expand` before the merge. Everything worked fine but saldy, the exported PDF is only slighly smaller (in the file I'm working currently it is 6MB to 5.2MB). Any other tricks to reduce the image size?

Comment: Open in Photoshop and save as a high quality JPG -- that'll kill the PDF file size considerably. But, of course, you won't have embedded vector data if that's the goal. And for commercial printing vector data is preferred - but then, for commercial printing file size should *never* be a concern.

Comment: Did you remember to remove the illustrator compatibility on export. Since without that the file is much smaller. Anyway why would the file size be a problem?

Comment: @joojaa Thanks! That helped a lot! I indeed forgot to uncheck this checkbox.